# angularjs access another form from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<ng-form name="innerForm">                                      
    <select ng-model="obj1" ng-options="i as i for i in selectTrueFalse" my-drective">...</select>
</ng-form>

<ng-form name="innerForm">                                      
    <select ng-model="obj2" ng-options="i as i for i in selectTrueFalse" my-drective">...</select>
</ng-form>
```

Two select elements above are wrapped around separate form element. In angularjs directive we can access the current form as mentioned below but as far as I know it only gives access to the current form. I need to access other form in order to access the element inside other form e.g. if the directive is being evaluated for obj1 how to access obj2 at that time. Is there a way?

```
app.directive('myDirective'), function() {
    return {
        require: '^form'
```

Comment: Why do you want to access another form elements?

Comment: @dfsq For cross field validation. I have two dropdowns having values yes/no, on value change validation fails if both the dropdowns have selected 'No'. The problem here is the error message of the current dropdown disappears when validation passes but it still shows the error message under another dropdown untill we change the value of that dropdown again and that meets the condition to pass. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You can use services, or events.